# DOT gives "triangulation failed" error

Tags: graphviz, dot

I have a .dot file and I am using command line to plot a graph using the dot file in pdf format using the following command

$ dot -Tpdf -O output_model.dot

I am getting the following error:

libpath/shortest.c:315: triangulation failed 
libpath/shortest.c:183: source point not in any triangle.

Any ideas why am I seeing this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without seeing the contents of your .dot file it is difficult to know. But, I've had a similar error when  using the constraint=false parameter on the edges in a graph.

Comment: Thanks Paul! It was indeed the same issue with me.

Comment: Just wondering, this answer does not seem to provide a solution, just an observation? What was the actual solution, if I may ask?