# triangulation failed, source point not in any triangle

Tags: graphviz, dot

When I ask dot to render the following:

```
digraph foo {
   GRAPH [rankdir="LR" nodesep=".3" ranksep=".3"];
   NODE  [shape="box"  width=".2"   height=".2" ];

   D;E;F;A;B;C;G;

   A->G; B->C; B->G; C->G; D->A; D->E; E->B; E->D; E->F; F->C; F->E;

   {rank="same"; A; B; C;}
   {rank="same"; D; E; F;}
}
```

I get the error "**triangulation failed, source point not in any triangle**";

Changing the rankdir to "TB" makes the error go away, and the output (image rendered) is:

[image]

unlike [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488064/dot-gives-triangulation-failed-error), adding a **constraint="true"** (or false) doesn't resolve the problem.

Have you seen this before? Is there a work-around?

Comment: can you show how you set rankdir to TB? graph viz newbie using the command from another library with graphviz...
depcruise --exclude "^node_modules" --output-type dot rankdir="TB" src | dot -T svg > dependencygraph.svg

Comment: @ShanonJackson in the code snippet above, where it says rankdir="LR" write rankdir="TB"

Comment: Solved it yesterday thanks